# Building installer Reputation with Windows SmartScreen

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, smartscreen

In recent years it has become impossible to have a downloadable windows app without using an SSL cert to sign your install executable so that Windows SmartScreen doesn't put up warnings (and even delete the file) when clients download it.

There are two types of SSL certs that you can use:

1. A regular Cert which can be for either a company or an individual.
2. An EV Cert, which costs 3x as much and can only be issued to a company.

The problem with the regular cert is that is doesn't immediately get you past SmartScreen.  You have to "build your reputation" first... which I believe means you have to have enough people download your product (possibly downloading it specifically with Microsoft Edge browser) that they start to believe you are not a virus maker or some such thing.

The problem is, I cannot find any guidance anywhere on how long it takes to build a "reputation".  10 downloads?  Easy 50 downloads? Sure.  10000 downloads?  That would require spending a lot of money on an advertising campaign that would not convert.

Does anyone have any experience that could help narrow this range down?